# Formatar TextBox para milhares?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando criar um TextBox para informar valores em milhares, os valores serão para pesos(kilos). Quero digitar os valores da direita para a esquerda baseado na máscara `0,000` e conforme o usuário for digitando o peso os valores vão sendo sobrescritos nos zeros...Por exemplo: `0,000` digitando o 1 irá ficar `0,001` e assim sucessivamente, se o usuário apagar o 1 a máscara retorna para `0,000` como no padrão.

Encontrei um exemplo para fazer isso que funciona muito bem, mas a classe é para valores monetários  e estou tentando adaptar para usar pesos mas não estou conseguindo adaptar.

Como fazer isso ?

Aqui a classe Moeda que estou usando como exemplo para adaptar a classe Peso.

```
public class Moeda  {
        private TextBox txtBox;
        private String txt = string.Empty;
        private Decimal valor = 0;

        public Moeda(TextBox txtBox) {
            this.txtBox = txtBox;
            this.txtBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            this.txtBox.Text = "0,00";
            this.txtBox.KeyPress += keyPress;
            this.txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textChanged);            
            this.txtBox.Font = new Font(this.txtBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);            
        }

        private void textChanged(object obj, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                txt = txtBox.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
                if (txt.Equals("")) {
                    txtBox.Text = "0,00";
                }
                txt = txt.PadLeft(3, '0');                
                if (txt.Length > 3 & txt.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
                    txt = txt.Substring(1, txt.Length - 1);
                valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txt) / 100;
                txtBox.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", valor);
                txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }            
        }

        private void keyPress(object obj, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
            if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))) { e.Handled = true; }
        }
    }
```

Aqui a classe Peso que estou tentando adaptar baseado na classe Moeda.

```
public class Peso  {
        private TextBox txtBox;
        private String txt = string.Empty;
        private Decimal valor = 0;

        public Peso(TextBox txtBox) {
            this.txtBox = txtBox;
            this.txtBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;             
            this.txtBox.Text = "0,000";
            this.txtBox.KeyPress += keyPress;
            this.txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textChanged);           
            this.txtBox.Font = new Font(this.txtBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);            
        }

        private void textChanged(object obj, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                txt = txtBox.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
                if (txt.Equals("")) {
                    txtBox.Text = "0,000";
                }
                txt = txt.PadLeft(4, '0');
                if (txt.Length > 4 & txt.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
                    txt = txt.Substring(1, txt.Length - 1);
                valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txt);
                txtBox.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", valor);
                txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }       
        }


        private void keyPress(object obj, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
            if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))) { e.Handled = true; }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Qual é sua dificuldade?

Comment: @bigown se vc puder, por favor, teste as 2 classes para vc ver como funcionam. A classe Peso não funciona como deveria. Para testar basta criar um TextBox no Form e no Load do Form fazer `new Peso(SeuTextBox)`

Comment: Não é mais fácil você explicar qual o comportamento esperado e qual está sendo o comportamento atual?

Comment: @jbueno mas eu ja relatei no post o comportamento esperado. Eu quero ir digitando os numeros de 0 a 9 a ir substituindo os 0 por eles, como em um caixa de banco. Na classe Moeda acontece isso, se vc puder testar, por favor, vai ver que é assim.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva eu não tenho nada instalado aqui, então não posso testar, de qualquer forma, não é pra gente testar, pra pra você dizer qual é o problema.

Comment: @bigown ja que não tem como vc testar e eu não tenho como dizer o que há de errado de maneira que seja clara e vc entenda, fiz um vídeo para mostrar o que está acontecendo. Veja: https://youtu.be/361vOJ5F1KQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, descobri que se dividir o "valor" por 1000, resulta no formato com 3 zeros antes da vírgula como você deseja.
Modifica esta linha:

```
valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txt);
```

com este valor:

```
valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txt) / 1000;
```

e complementa desta forma:

```
txtBox.Text = String.Format("{0:N3}", valor);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: perfeito, obrigado !